# Machine Learning Model using Google Analytics Data

Tags: python, google-analytics

I have used Google Analytics to help my company design a comprehensive website tracking architecture, complete with a wide range of events. It has been completed, and now I want to start creating user models. Has anyone worked with Google Analytics 360 data, including events and pageviews, to build any consumer models? I would appreciate any experience or reference you can share.

Are there any code examples or websites you can recommend to me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.